# How can I select information where the condition is in multiple rows?

Tags: sql, request

How can I select some information from the `User` table (for example `NAME` and `SURNAME`) where, in the `Option` table, the user I want to select the information having the option `20` and also the option `25`, for example ?

In this example, I want to select the `NAME` and `SURNAME` of user `1` because it's the only one to have both the option `20` and `25`.

**`Option` table**:

```
+---------+---------+
| ID_USER | OPTIONS |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 20      |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 25      |
+---------+---------+
| 2       | 20      |
+---------+---------+
| 3       | 25      |
+---------+---------+
```

**`User` table**:

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| ID_USER | NAME    | SURNAME  |
+---------+---------+----------+
| 1       | Jean    | Baptiste |
+---------+---------+----------+
| 2       | Henry   | Charles  |
+---------+---------+----------+
| 3       | Jacques | François |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

**The result table**:

```
+------+----------+
| NAME | SURNAME  |
+------+----------+
| Jean | Baptiste |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: Specify the expected result - in table format.

Comment: Just a note, shouldn't this be a many to many relationship? One user can have one or more options and one option can belong to one or more users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `JOIN` to get the combinations, use `WHERE` to filter out the expected options. `GROUP BY` combined with `HAVING COUNT DISTINCT` to make sure both 20 and 25 values are there.

```
select u.NAME, u.SURNAME
from User u
join Option o on o.ID_USER = u.ID_USER
where o.options IN (20, 25)
group by u.NAME, u.SURNAME
having count(distinct o.options) = 2
```

**Note:** `USER` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit it as `"User"`.

Comment: Thank that exactly what I wanted => Make sure both 20 and 25 values are there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question, but I think that the following select would do:

```
SELECT NAME , SURENAME
  FROM User
 WHERE ID_User IN (SELECT ID_User 
                     FROM Option
                    WHERE OPTIONS IN (20,25)
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.name,u.surname

FROM user u, option o

WHERE u.id_user=o.id_user

AND o.options IN (20,25)
```